# SNMP Trap Truncated?

Tags: net-snmp, snmp-trap

So we receive an SNMP trap and the text is as follows:

The following SNMP trap notification was generated by ms931.mytest.com (xx.x.xxx.xx):

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance  0:0:21:08.75
        SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteTriggerFired
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger.0  44448217: No response from lo  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTargetName.0
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotContextName.0  
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotOID.0  SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.7143.6.9.1.0
  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotValue.0  1224  SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.7143.6.9.2.0  7
```

Essentially the line with the error code (i.e. 44448217) some how gets truncated. Or the line that follows eats it up or something. The snmpd service, that we use, is being run on Linux RH 5.6 and the RPM package version is net-snmp-5.3.2.2-9.el5_5.1. We have the 44448217 error message that we provide but why is it being truncated? This didn't happen with net-snmp-5.1.2-13.el4_7.2.

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: That's a pretty old Net-SNMP version. The latest is 5.7.1. Try upgrading and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to have been also asked (and answered) [in this Google group for Net-SNMP users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.unix.net-snmp-users/yy944BJfzwc).

To summarize the conversation there, the information was *internally* being truncated and had nothing to do with the *trap* itself.  There were hard limits to the length of the text that were not followed, and thus the posted result.

---

DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger, the OID whose value appears to be truncated, is an SnmpAdminString that represents a trigger name.  While an SnmpAdminString can be up to 255 bytes in length, the trigger names from DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteTriggerName can only be up to 32 bytes in length.

The trigger name was specified in the particular configuration as:

> 44448217: No response from local user/portal application.

This was well over the 32-byte limit.  The solution was simply to make the trigger *name* the *error code* value:

> 44448217

(which worked out fine for the poster).

---

In theory, if the entire trigger table were to have been walked, the value of DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteTriggerName would have also appeared to have been truncated.  That information would have been helpful to this post if it were originally provided.